# combine multiple weighted averages

Tags: sequences-and-series, average

Suppose there is a dataset  $X = [x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ where each element $x_i$ has a set of features (weights) $A_i = [a^1_i, a^2_i, \cdots , a^k_i]$. We then can have a multiple weighted average according to each feature like following:
$\bar{x}^1=\frac{\sum_i a^1_ix_i}{\sum_i a^1_i}$ and $\bar{x}^2=\frac{\sum_i a^2_ix_i}{\sum_i a^2_i}$; $\cdots$  $\bar{x}^k=\frac{\sum_i a^k_ix_i}{\sum_i a^k_i}$

Is there a standard method of combining all the $k$ weighted average and what is the pros/cons of such approach? Some ways I can think of are

- [1] Averaging all the weighted average: $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_j\bar{x^j}$ (We can then add a secondary set of weights for each of the $k$ features to this sum.)
- [2] duplicate the set for $k$ times, taking the weighted sum of each set. taking the sum of weighted sum and divided by the sum of all weights of all sets.

I want to create an average metric that takes into account all the $k$ features but the issue is the features are not of the same magnitude or unit so it seems like approach [2] would suffer if one feature is an order of magnitude bigger than the rest. Is there any way to deal with this/combining feature beside normalizing them?

Comment: You can come up with any computation you'd like, but what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How you choose to combine these individual averages to produce a single statistic depends entirely on what makes sense in your application.

Comment: i'm trying to come up with an average that takes into account all the feature of each datapoint @vallev

Comment: Try to specify what you want to achieve in more detail. Or give more context so that people can help to specify that.